# Deserializing Json to an Array type Propoerty

Tags: c#

I am new to Json. I am trying to populate my object 'Sources' from json string with:

```
public class Sources  
{
   public long[] SourceIds;
}


string jsonstring = " [\r\n {\r\n  \"SourceIds\": 20181234\r\n  }, \r\n 
{\r\n  \"SourceIds\": 20181234\r\n  },\r\n {\r\n  \"SourceIds\": 
20181234\r\n  }\r\n]"
```

My aim is to have an object of 'Sources' with the values of 'SourceIds' populated.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried so far? Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a question.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your actual Json is like below:

```
string jsonstring = " [
 {
      \"SourceIds\": 20181234
  },  
  {
      \"SourceIds\": 20181234
  },
 {
      \"SourceIds\": 20181234
  }
]"
```

You can serialize your json with

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<Class1>>(String)
```

Serialization Classes

```
public class Class1
{
    public int SourceIds { get; set; }
}
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rAqcye)